# XMLSerializer doesn't serialize class properties and returns only bool - 'false' values for *Specified members

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

Having class code autogenerated by WCF/svcutil.exe like that:

```
public class Foo
{

    private float barField;

    bool barFieldSpecified;

    public float bar
    {
        get
        {
            return this.barField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.barField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapIgnore]
    public bool barSpecified
    {
        get
        {
            return this.barFieldSpecified;
        }
        set
        {
            this.barFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }        
}
```

and using XMLSerializer like that:

```
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.bar = 100;
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        ser.Serialize(ms, foo);
        var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
```

I get XML with values in all nodes set to 'false' and none of my class properties I set.

Comment: Plase add some code from the pastebin file into this post - because if the bastebin snipped becomes unavailable this post would no longer be helpful or even understandable.

Comment: could you point out where in the 3000 lines of code it goes wrong?

Comment: Holy moly. Maybe that's the XmlSerializer's way of saying `NOPE`. Perhaps you can post your usage of the XmlSerializer?

Comment: To add to @Spontifixus said, posting a whole class and asking for help will not get you an answer.  Show some effort that you tried to troubleshoot it by creating a concise test example with sample input and if you are still having trouble, post that.

Comment: Also, you've posted a partial class, is there content in the other partial that's relevant? Perhaps you can also post the XML output you're getting.

Comment: sorry, you're all right but it was hard do extract problematic parts. Luckly, I realized what was the problem. Thanks for commenting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason of such behaviour is that XMLSerializer make usage of these additional properties ending with 'Specified' keyword for value-typed properties like `bar` and `barSpecified` in code above. If `barSpecified` is not set to 'true', `bar` property will not be serialized. It's XMLSerializer's way of saying that `bar` is kind of NULL and shouldn't be serialized.

There are at least 3 possibilities for solving that:

-removing `barSpecified` property and field

-setting `barSpecified` to 'true'

-if class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` make usage of it (if class is autogenerated it's good to make it as partial class in another file like below):

```
   public partial class Foo
   {
        public Foo()
        {
            this.PropertyChanged += (object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e) =>
                {
                    if (!e.PropertyName.EndsWith("Specified"))
                    {
                        var prop = this.GetType().GetProperty(e.PropertyName + "Specified");
                        if (prop != null)
                            prop.SetValue(this, true, null);
                    }
                };
        }
    }
```